# jQuery .not() doesn't remove element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

I am grabbing a copy of some info from a page, but I do not want to include certain `<option>` elements that appear inside `<select>` elements on the page.

Therefore, while I grab all the elements I want and am storing them in the variable `fields`, I check to see if each element is a `<select>` and if they have the specific `<option>` that I don't want.

```
var field = allFields[i].innerHTML;                      //allFields is the raw HTML I'm iterating through
if ($(field).find("select").length > 0) {                //If the element we're looking at contains a select
  console.log("Found a select. It is in " + field);
  console.log($(field).find(".bad-option");
  field = $(field).not(".bad-option").prop("outerHTML"); //Use .not() to remove the elements which have the .bad-option class
                                                         // (and .prop("outerHTML") is just there to convert it back to a String instead of a jQuery object)
}
console.log("Adding " + field);
fields[i] = field;                                      //Add the HTML, free of any unwanted options, to the `fields` variable
```

Based on [jQuery's documentation](https://api.jquery.com/not/), I would expect the `.not()` function to remove any elements out of `field` which have the `bad-option` class. Yet that is not the case at all. When I log `field` before and after using `.not()`, it prints out the same thing. See the console output from the code above:

```
Found a select. It is in <label>Description:&nbsp;<select><option>thing1</option><option class="bad-option">thing2</option></select></label>
-----------------
[jQuery list object size 1, containing an object called option.bad-option]
-----------------
Adding <label>Description:&nbsp;<select><option>thing1</option><option class="bad-option">thing2</option></select></label>
```

So what's going on? How do I remove an option with a certain class from from within a jQuery object? Why isn't `.not()` working?

If I need to clarify anything, please let me know. I tried to make this question as specific as possible and would be happy to elaborate on any details further.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation is perhaps a bit confusing: `not` removes elements from the **selection**, not the DOM. If you want to remove the elements, then just filter and remove:

```js
const processed = $(field);
processed.filter(".bad-option").remove();
field = processed.prop("outerHTML");
```

Comment: Hm, I copied your code exactly, but strangely it seems to change nothing. console.logging `processed` indeed gives the jQuery object representation of `field`. But after the `.filter()` and `.prop()` lines, logging again just gives the exact same HTML as before, still with the `<option class="bad-option">` element in it.